# How does React treats variables assignment?

Tags: reactjs

My problem is that errorMessage is always set to "intitial", although I am assigning it to  "Invalid Input - Please enter a valid name and age (non-empty values).";
but the same is not reflected at all. What concept am I missing?
Basically, in this `{!valid  && <Validation>{errorMessage}</Validation>}` , errorMessage is always initial but it doesn't reflect to what I am setting inside the userInputHandler.
Also, if don't initialize errorMessage i.e. simply say let errorMessage then the console says - errorMessage undefined. I am sure I am missing some fundamental here.
What is it?

```
import "./App.css";
import UserInput from "./Components/UserInput/UserInput";
import Validation from "./Components/Validation/Validation";
import { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const UserList = [];

  const [valid, setValid] = useState(true);

  let errorMessage = "Initial";

  const userInputHandler = (userData) => {
    //console.log(userData);
    if (userData.user.trim() === "" || userData.age === 0) {
      console.log(
        "Invalid Input - Please enter a valid name and age (non-empty values)."
      );
      errorMessage =
        "Invalid Input - Please enter a valid name and age (non-empty values).";
      setValid(false);
      
    }

    else if (userData.age < 0) {
      console.log("Invalid input  Please enter a valid age (>0).");
      errorMessage = "Invalid input  Please enter a valid age (>0).";
      setValid(false);
    } 
    else {
      setValid(true);
      userData.id = Math.random();
      UserList.push(userData);
      console.log("hello", UserList);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <UserInput onUserInput={userInputHandler} />
      {console.log(errorMessage)}
      {!valid  && <Validation>{errorMessage}</Validation>}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: When you need something that changes, use state, just like you're doing with `valid`

Answer (score 0):

It's not re-rendering what you're displaying in the return function once it's changed by the if statements, so as CertainPerformance says you need to change all the instances of errorMessage = to something like setErrorMessage(), and change the first initialisation to const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = setState("Initial")